Is it natural to say "you should've done the math exercise smartly"?

This is my daughter's math question.
The way she did it is to count every cell one by one, which is not effective.
So I told her "the first line is 10 and the second is 10 so we have 20 and we have 3 in the third. That amounts to 23".
Is it natural to say "you should've done the math exercise smartly"?
But "smartly" sounds strange and it might not be common.
Maybe "do it wisely" sounds better.

More natural would be to say "A smarter way would be to ...."

Not necessarily suitable for addressing a child, but "You could have approached the problem with lateral thinking" would be natural phrasing among adults.

@FumbleFingers, Do American people say it. It is more common in Britain right?

The term was coined by de Bono (originally Maltese, but worked in the UK more than the US). So it's more common in BrE, but I'd expect most reasonably knowledgeable Americans to be familiar with the usage today, since it's a useful term, and I'm not aware of any equivalent with significant currency.

@FumbleFingers, is "creatively" roughly the same as "with lateral thinking"?

Gimme a break! I put a link to Wikipedia for "lateral thinking" in my first comment. Go read it! I'd have thought if your own language doesn't have an equivalent, "lateral thinking" ought to be just imported wholesale, the way English import things like "schadenfreude" and "kindergarten".

@FumbleFingers, that word is too much for a child and it is not common in the USA anyway. It's too technical. Only University students should use it.

"Clever" is probably better than "wise" or "smart": "mentally quick and resourceful", "marked by wit or ingenuity". But "You should have been cleverer" or "you should have done it more cleverly" is better than "done it cleverly".

I feel very sorry for your daughter. Just give her a break and let her play. None of this will help the poor thing improve her math.  And I hope you aren't trying to say these things to her in English.  You need to be smarter about how you communicate with her. Right now, you're getting a D- from me.

Sorry, but no. "Smart" can mean "intelligent", but "smartly" means "stylishly", like, "Sally was very smartly dressed". Or it can mean "promptly" or "quickly", like, "When he heard a loud noise, he sat up smartly." Yes, this can be confusing -- that's what makes English such a fun language to learn!
You could say, "You should try to solve the problem more thoughtfully". That's the closest in meaning I can think of to what it appears you are trying to say.

(Plus, saying that, no matter how you word it, sends a very bad instructional message. There is no wrong way to do it… and even if she got the wrong answer, making mistakes—lots and lots of them—is key to learning math. It should never be belittled: that’s how people end up with the idea that math is about solving problems rather than about exploring and finding patterns… and those patterns aren’t—and needn’t be—the patterns that seem “best” to you.)

Idiomatically, I think more people would probably go with should have done it more carefully rather than thoughtfully. Perhaps your choice may have been affected by the semantics of OP's completely non-idiomatic [more] wisely.

But actually, it's not so much more thought that's needed - it's creative thought.

@FumbleFingers Sure, many words could fit here, depending on just what you're trying to convey. I was thinking that the speaker is trying to say that the student should have thought more carefully, and so I suggested "thoughtfully". You'd get a similar meaning if you said "intelligently", but that would be harsher as it implies the student was foolish. "Creatively" also works if you're trying to say that a better solution involves more creativity and less brute force hard work, which I think is also an idea the OP is trying to convey.

Your "intelligently" ... would be harsher as it implies the student was foolish is exactly what I had in the back of my mind! It's not usually constructive to "urge" students to "make an effort" to find a simple approach. In my experience, the best way to encourage more lateral thinking is by saying things like "Here's a clever trick to get the answer more quickly with less effort". The student doesn't feel he's being taken to task for failing to see the trick in advance, but he'll probably be strongly motivated to look out for comparable contexts in the future!

@FumbleFingers Yes, that is probably the only answer here that comes closed to working.

@FumbleFingers Maybe so. But this forum is about language and not about pedagogy! My  point was not to discuss the best way to encourage a student to look for better ways to solve a problem, but simply to discuss what English words can be used to describe it all. :-)

@PaulTanenbaum There certainly are wrong ways to solve a problem. If a student said that she determined the number of squares by consulting her horoscope, I'd say that was just wrong, even if she managed to come up with the right answer. (If she consistently got the right answer by consulting her horoscope, I might be rethinking my views on astrology. :-) And there are better and worse ways to solve a problem. Like in this example, if a student gets the right answer but uses a very long and arduous process and there's a much easier way, I think it's a good thing ...

... to tell the student the easier way, or to help her find it. Leaving her to solve a problem the hard way is going to encourage her to think of math as tedious and boring.

@Jay, I certainly agree that guiding a student is extremely valuable. And I suppose that “there is no wrong way” is indeed an overstatement. But counting isn’t astrology: it’s perfectly valid. And anyway, my point still stands, “You should have done it smartly” sounds a lot less like guidance than like a put down. And, regardless of its intent, it runs the risk of being internalized as “I am not smart. I am stupid.”

What you have found is a "shortcut".  Or a "quick" way to do the problem.  You might recommend that she should "work smarter, not harder" But that is clichéd.
As usual, there isn't a "right thing to say".  You can put together words according to their meanings and the rules of grammar.  You don't need to learn a phrase for every situation.
Generally telling a person to be "smarter" is bad advice, since it is not something that they can do.  Suppose I told you that you should stop making mistakes in English?  It doesn't help you very much!  But telling them to look for shortcuts might be good advice.

Everybody likes a shortcut, but it's especially welcome when someone in authority or a teaching role shows you a shortcut. It makes whatever you need to do easier and/or quicker, with no fear of being taken to task for not doing things "the proper (i.e. - longer, harder) way".
